# System command not working properly in Perl script

Tags: perl

Changing permission of specific directory using Perl script. Script is running properly but not changing permission of directory.

```
system("chmod 0777 $dir");
```

`$dir`: path is declared in this variable.

Failed to set permission.

Comment: Try running the script with `system("chmod 0777 $dir") and die "Cannot change permissions";` to have error checking.

Comment: Its not working I have tried it already

Comment: Why do you need to use system? Perl has `chmod` built-in.. simply try `chmod '0777', $dir`

Comment: @sergiotarxz but that would cause a custom error message. `system("chmod 0777 $dir") or die "$!"`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. Include the current owner and permissions of the file, and under which user (and group) you run your code. Include the `and die ...` part @sergiotarxz mentioned. Can you `chmod` the file on the shell?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard That should be `and die`, not `or die`. `system` returns `0` on success.

Comment: @melpomene, yes, I cannot edit it, but I was refering to `$!`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you why your command failed, because you did  not give enough detail, but there is no need to use `system` in this case as Perl has `chmod` built in and it behaves exactly the same.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = "/some/dir";
chmod 0777, $dir or die "$!";
```

This will also give you a valid error message if the command failed.

You can also do list of directories and files.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @dirs = ("dir1", "dir2");
my $each = chmod 0777, @dirs;
print "$each modified\n";
die $! if ($!);
```

Comment: I would include `$dir` in the error message. In the second case, a successful `chmod` will not set `$!` to `0`, so you can't rely on that. You'd need to check if `$each == @dirs`.